# Conflicting types error for function taking void* in public API and typed* under the hood

Tags: c, function, types

I'm trying to build a 3rd party library which has a function defined in the public header as such

```
void reset(void* instance);
```

And in the implementation

```
void reset(instance_type* instance) {
   ...
}
```

And I'm getting a conflicting types compiler error. Now this seems obvious why to me on the surface. The author was using MSVC and I'm using gcc set to C99 standard - maybe that's why it worked on the authors machine? What's the minimal modification I can make to get this to build under the constraint that I don't want to expose the `instance_type` through the public interface?

Comment: If you don't want to expose the type, then you'll have to use a generic pointer type, or a typedef of it.

Comment: So cast from void* in the function definition @ThomasJager?

Comment: What precisely do you mean by the typedef suggestion @ThomasJager?

Comment: @leanvst I mean that you could create a typedef to `void` and use a pointer to that type, as the publicly-exposed type. It doesn't change anything other than just being a clue as to that the value is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the minimal modification I can make to get this to build under the constraint that I don't want to expose the `instance_type` through the public interface?

It is necessary for the definition to agree with the declaration in the header.  If you don't want to expose `instance_type` in the public API, then that means modifying the definition to match the header:

```
void reset(void* _instance) {
   instance_type* instance = _instance;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Cool - that was my suggestion to @ThomasJager in the thread under the original question